# Where clause query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have query the output is supposed to show all medically trained staff and all volunteers that have first aid:

```
SELECT Concat (s.staff_fname, ' ', s.staff_lname)        AS Staff_Name, 
   s.medically_trained, 
   s.staff_email_address, 
   Concat(v.volunteer_fname, ' ', v.volunteer_lname) AS Volunteer_Name, 
   v.first_aid, 
   v.volunteer_email_address 
FROM   volunteer v 
   JOIN staff s 
     ON v.volunteerid = s.staffid 
WHERE  s.medically_trained = ' yes' 
   AND v.first_aid = ' yes'
```

however when I execute my code it says empty set. What am I doing wrong?

I am a beginner coder so please dont judge if ive made an obvious mistake lol

THANK YOU!

Comment: Post sample data and table structure in your question.  But one thing, your where conditions have spaces before the 'yes' ->  `' yes'`   Is that intentional?

Comment: Your query has `' yes'` in the `WHERE` clause. Does that column *literally* contain the value `space, lowercase-y, lowercase-e, lowercase-s` to indicate a true value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the space from 'yes' , it may also cause this issue.You may get the not null value in result.

If it is still blank then try to run the where clause individually on both of the tables,

Select * 
FROM   volunteer v where  v.first_aid = 'yes';

and 
   select * from staff s 
   WHERE  s.medically_trained = 'yes' ;

and check whether any one of it is giving you null as a result, if yes then your answer is correct.

Comment: It was because of the spaces in the yes, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces in `where` section:

```
SELECT Concat (s.staff_fname, ' ', s.staff_lname)        AS Staff_Name, 
   s.medically_trained, 
   s.staff_email_address, 
   Concat(v.volunteer_fname, ' ', v.volunteer_lname) AS Volunteer_Name, 
   v.first_aid, 
   v.volunteer_email_address 
FROM   volunteer v 
   JOIN staff s 
     ON v.volunteerid = s.staffid 
WHERE  s.medically_trained = 'yes'  /* <-- */ 
   AND v.first_aid = 'yes'    /* <-- */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `CONCAT('foo', 'null')`, the result will be `null`. Check to see if that's not the case.

Also, it could be from either the `JOIN` clause or `WHERE` clause. Try running the query without `JOIN` and then without the `WHERE` clause and see if you'll still have empty sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(s.staff_fname,' ', s.staff_lname)AS Name,s.medically_trained AS Trained,s.staff_email_address AS Email_Address,'STAFF' cType
FROM staff s
WHERE s.medically_trained = ' yes' 

UNION ALL

SELECT Concat(v.volunteer_fname, ' ', v.volunteer_lname) AS Name,v.first_aid AS Trained,v.volunteer_email_address AS Email_Address,'VOLUNTEER' cType
FROM volunteer v 
WHERE v.first_aid = ' yes'
```

I used UNION ALL for the two table because I dont think Volunteer_ID will be Equivalent to STAFF_ID. I included cType Column for you to identify if the record was from Staff table or Volunteer